# I get a "NullPointerException" when I'm trying to implement ListView Volley

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-volley

I've tried to do **everything** as in [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) tutorial: 
but I don't know what is the problem there.

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
            at info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6185)
```

Comment: Initialize your ActionBar before setting it's background.

Comment: What line is at your `onCreate()` method at MainActivity at line 55? To find out, go to the logcat where the crash happens, a line will contain `MainActivity.java:55` in blue, click there, it will take you to where the crash is

Comment: @AbAppletic thanks, I just commented these lines and compiled again. My error was so ridiculous. Thank you for your response :)